# Why am i getting poor results?

Tags: python-2.7, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

I am currently working on a Neural network that maps stft audio files to MFCC features..

But keep for some reason keep getting a validation_loss around 200. 
Which compared desired range is (-100,100)..   so the output the NN outputs is not desirable..

I tried different implementation..

Simple NN 1-layer, 2-layer, 3-layer => wiht no difference.

CNN , 1-layer, 2-layer => same result

tried with random forrest => never finished, memory allocation error.

So...

What am I doing wrong?
I tried normalizing the input and output, but the same error came back when i unormalized the dataset.. so...

the shape of the input is (x,2050) and the shape of the output (x,13)...

Any idea on why I am getting so poor results?..

Normalization:

```
def numpy_minmax(X):
    print X.min()
    print X.max()
    xmin =  X.min()
    return (2*(X - xmin) / (X.max() - xmin)-1)*0.9


def numpy_unorm(x):
    xmax = 109.2991
    xmin = -97.23664
    return x*(xmax-xmin)+xmin

files_train_path = [dnn_train+f for f in listdir(dnn_train) if isfile(join(dnn_train, f))]
files_test_path = [dnn_test+f for f in listdir(dnn_test) if isfile(join(dnn_test, f))]

files_train_name = [f for f in listdir(dnn_train) if isfile(join(dnn_train, f))]
files_test_name = [f for f in listdir(dnn_test) if isfile(join(dnn_test, f))]

os.chdir(dnn_train)

#train_name = generate_list_of_names_data(files_train_path)
#print train_name

train_data, train_output_data, max = load_sound_files(files_train_path)
#sys.exit()
#train_data_real, train_data_img = split_real_img(train_data)
#print train_data


train_set_data_vstacked = np.vstack(train_data)
train_set_output_vstacked = np.vstack(train_output_data)
print train_set_data_vstacked.shape

train_set_data_vstacked_normalized = numpy_minmax(train_set_data_vstacked)
train_set_output_vstacked_normalized = numpy_minmax(train_set_output_vstacked)
```

Currently network structure options tried:

```
############################### Training setup ##################################

#Define 10 folds:
seed = 7
np.random.seed(seed)
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=False, random_state=None)
print "Splits"
cvscores_acc = []
cvscores_loss = []
hist = []
i = 0
#train_set_data_vstacked_normalized_reshaped = np.reshape(train_set_data_vstacked_normalized,train_set_data_vstacked_normalized.shape+(1,))
#train_set_output_vstacked_normalized_reshaped = np.reshape(train_set_output_vstacked_normalized,train_set_output_vstacked_normalized.shape+(1,))
for train, test in kfold.split(train_set_data_vstacked_normalized):

    print "Model definition!"
    model = Sequential()

    #act = PReLU(init='normal', weights=None)
    model.add(Dense(output_dim=2050,input_dim=2050, init="normal", activation='relu'))

    #act1 = PReLU(init='normal', weights=None)

    #act2 = PReLU(init='normal', weights=None)
    model.add(Dense(output_dim=2050, input_dim=2050, init="he_normal",activation='tanh'))

    model.add(Dense(output_dim=13, input_dim=2050, init="he_normal",activation='tanh'))
    model.add(Lambda(lambda x: numpy_unorm(x)))

    #model.add(ELU(100))

    #model.add(Convolution1D(13, 3, border_mode='same', input_shape=(2050,1)))

    print "Compiling"
    #rms_opt = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.01, rho=0.9, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer="RMSprop")
    print "Compile done! "

    print '\n'

    print "Train start"

    reduce_lr=ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.01, patience=3, verbose=1, mode='auto', epsilon=0.0001, cooldown=0, min_lr=0.000000000000000001)
    stop  = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, patience=5, verbose=1, mode='auto')

    log=csv_logger = CSVLogger('training_'+str(i)+'.csv')


    hist_current = model.fit(train_set_data_vstacked_normalized[train],
                                train_set_output_vstacked[train],
                                shuffle=False,
                                validation_data=(train_set_data_vstacked_normalized[test],train_set_output_vstacked[test]),
                                validation_split=0.1,
                                nb_epoch=150,
                                verbose=1,
                                callbacks=[reduce_lr,log,stop])

    hist.append(hist_current)
```

Convolutional:

```
#Each frame length = 118
#Each feature length = 13
############################### Training setup ##################################

#Define 10 folds:
seed = 7
np.random.seed(seed)
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=False, random_state=None)
print "Splits"
cvscores_acc = []
cvscores_loss = []
hist = []
i = 0
#train_set_data_vstacked_normalized_reshaped = np.reshape(train_set_data_vstacked_normalized,train_set_data_vstacked_normalized.shape+(1,))
#train_set_output_vstacked_normalized_reshaped = np.reshape(train_set_output_vstacked_normalized,train_set_output_vstacked_normalized.shape+(1,))
train_set_data_vstacked_reshaped = train_set_data_vstacked[:,newaxis,:]
train_set_output_vstacked_reshaped = train_set_output_vstacked[:,newaxis,:]

print train_set_data_vstacked_reshaped.shape
print train_set_output_vstacked_reshaped.shape

for train, test in kfold.split(train_set_data_vstacked_reshaped):

    print "Model definition!"
    model = Sequential()

    #act = PReLU(init='normal', weights=None)
    #model.add(Dense(output_dim=400,input_dim=400, init="normal", activation=K.tanh))

    #act1 = PReLU(init='normal', weights=None)

    #act2 = PReLU(init='normal', weights=None)
    #model.add(Dense(output_dim=2050, input_dim=2050, init="he_normal",activation='tanh'))

    #model.add(Dense(output_dim=13, input_dim=2050, init="he_normal",activation='relu'))
    #model.add(Lambda(lambda x: numpy_unorm(x)))

    #model.add(ELU(100))

    model.add(Convolution1D(2050, 1, border_mode='same', input_dim=2050))
    model.add(Convolution1D(13, 1, border_mode='same', input_dim=2050))
    #model.add(Convolution1D(13, 1, border_mode='same', input_dim=2050))
    #model.add(Dense(output_dim=13, input_dim=2050, init="he_normal",activation='relu'))

    print "Compiling"
    #rms_opt = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.01, rho=0.9, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer="Adam")
    print "Compile done! "

    print '\n'

    print "Train start"

    reduce_lr=ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.01, patience=3, verbose=1, mode='auto', epsilon=0.01, cooldown=0, min_lr=0.000000000000000001)
    stop  = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, patience=5, verbose=1, mode='auto')

    log=csv_logger = CSVLogger('training_'+str(i)+'.csv')


    hist_current = model.fit(train_set_data_vstacked_reshaped[train],
                                train_set_output_vstacked_reshaped[train],
                                shuffle=False,
                                validation_data=(train_set_data_vstacked_reshaped[test],train_set_output_vstacked_reshaped[test]),
                                validation_split=0.1,
                                nb_epoch=150,
                                verbose=1,
                                callbacks=[reduce_lr,log,stop])

    hist.append(hist_current)
```

Comment: Does it work when you normalize input/outputs? NNs need normalized data to be able to train successfully.

Comment: The error range is in 0.015.. but when I unnormalize such that i can use it in my application,  increases the error as well..

Comment: Then you need to train the neural network for more epochs, or with a different learning rate/optimizer, or change the architecture, in order to decrease the error to what your application considers tolerable.

Comment: I am currently using  rmsprop as optimizer.. any suggestions on what else i can try.. 
I am currently running it for 150 epochs..

Comment: And should i keep doing it with normalised data and unnormalize it at the end with a lambda layer?

Comment: Try ADAM, change the neural network architecture, and yes, always use normalized data. You could even train it for more epochs and see if it decreases the error. Also increasing the batch size could help.

Comment: Well.. The error  seem to flatline around there, even if I increase the epochs.... but what about the unnormalization..

Comment: I added the code in case you could spot something obvious..

Comment: I already mentioned that you should modify the network structure, add more layers for example, whatever makes sense for your data.

Comment: Same goes for adding layers..  training time increases but no decrease in error rate..

Comment: Its not as simple as just adding layers, you also have to tune the hyperparameters of each layer, and that will take time (grid or random search). I also don't see any regularization in your model. In any case there are too many things you can try and this is not the best place to discuss them all